# snapshot of current OS including all dependencies and libraries and some specified folders

Tags: boot, bootloader, iso, live-cd

I need to make snapshot of my current OS including all dependencies and libraries and some specified folders.
Folks from IRC just advised cubic to make some kind of iso (? live cd).
Basically It does not look like what I would really need.

Ideally I want to make distributive of my OS (Ubuntu 22) and my current OS state.
What would you advise.